# ASP.Net display list through severals pages number

Tags: c#, asp.net

I work with ASP.NET web forms and i have a question. There is a default page (represent the home page) called **Default.aspx**.

In my C# code behind, i have a list. I want to display this list throught severals pages. For exemple, my list have 10 items and i want display 5 items by page :

- first page (5 items) : Default.aspx
- second page (5 others items) : Default.aspx?**page=2**

And this, dynamicly. So i want 5 items by page. If my list have 15 items, so there will 3 pages ; if my list 30 items, 6 pages, etc.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You could use one page and display the items for example in a `GridView` with paging where the [`PageSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagesize(v=vs.100).aspx) is 5.

Comment: Ok, i will see that. thanks